# Performance monitoring is not uploaded by sentry-expo

Tags: react-native, expo, sentry

I want to implement Automatic Instrumentation from sentry documentation, but it is not uploading.
https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/performance/instrumentation/automatic-instrumentation/
I'm checking on IOS only.
react-native app uses bare workflow for expo. I use sentry's TEAM plan.Is it a bare work flow, so it needs to be set up differently than the document? I have confirmed that I am running `react-native link @sentry/react-native`.
https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-sentry/

- expo ^43.0.0
- sentry-expo ^4.0.0
- expo-device 4.0.3
- expo-constants 12.1.3
- @sentry/react-native 3.4.1
- @react-navigation/native ^5.7.6
- @react-navigation/stack ^5.9.3

```
// App.tsx
import * as Sentry from "sentry-expo";
import { routingInstrumentation } from "./RootNavigator";

Sentry.init({
    dsn: SENTRY_DNS,
    enableInExpoDevelopment: true,
    debug: true,
    environment: isDevProject ? "development" : "production",
    integrations: [
      new Sentry.Native.ReactNativeTracing({
        routingInstrumentation
      })
    ]
  });

const App = () => {
...
export default Sentry.Native.wrap(App);

// RootNavigator.tsx
export const routingInstrumentation =
  new Sentry.Native.ReactNavigationInstrumentation();

export const RootNavigator = () => {
  const navigation = useRef();
  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      ref={navigation}
      onReady={() => {
        routingInstrumentation.registerNavigationContainer(navigation);
      }}
    >
      <RootStack />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

log

```
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: Release
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: InboundFilters
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: FunctionToString
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: Breadcrumbs
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: LinkedErrors
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: Dedupe
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: UserAgent
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: EventOrigin
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: SdkInfo
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: DebugSymbolicator
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: DeviceContext
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: Unhandled promise rejections will be caught by Sentry.
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: ReactNativeErrorHandlers
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: ExpoBareIntegration
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: RewriteFrames
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: [ReactNativeTracing] Native frames instrumentation initialized.
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: Setting idle transaction on scope. Span ID: b83d8034e147174f
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: [ReactNativeTracing] Starting navigation transaction "Route Change" on scope
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: ReactNativeTracing
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] No active IdleTransaction
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] Discarding transaction because its trace was not chosen to be sampled.
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] No active IdleTransaction
 WARN  Constants.installationId has been deprecated in favor of generating and storing your own ID. Implement it using expo-application's androidId on Android and a storage API such as expo-secure-store on iOS and localStorage on the web. This API will be removed in SDK 44.
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: [ReactNavigationInstrumentation] Navigation container registered, but integration has not been setup yet.
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: Setting idle transaction on scope. Span ID: 9b853cb1f7205d52
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: [ReactNativeTracing] Starting navigation transaction "Route Change" on scope
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: [ReactNavigationInstrumentation] Will not send transaction "HomeScreen" due to beforeNavigate.
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: Setting idle transaction on scope. Span ID: 8ff341d5619f89aa
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: [ReactNativeTracing] Starting navigation transaction "Route Change" on scope
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: Setting idle transaction on scope. Span ID: a7c139b65d6cab41
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: [ReactNativeTracing] Starting navigation transaction "Route Change" on scope
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] No active IdleTransaction
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] Discarding transaction because its trace was not chosen to be sampled.
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] No active IdleTransaction
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] Discarding transaction because its trace was not chosen to be sampled.
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] No active IdleTransaction
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] Discarding transaction because its trace was not chosen to be sampled.
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: Setting idle transaction on scope. Span ID: bff56876a83da89c
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: [ReactNativeTracing] Starting navigation transaction "Route Change" on scope
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] No active IdleTransaction
 LOG  Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] Discarding transaction because its trace was not chosen to be sampled.
```

[Screen of sentory's dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7EyG.png)

Comment: I am facing the same issue, how did you fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find more about the tracesSampleRate property and how to set it for production and development in the Sentry docs.

Setting a uniform sample rate for all transactions using the tracesSampleRate option in your SDK config to a number between 0 and 1. (For example, to send 20% of transactions, set tracesSampleRate to 0.2.)

More on: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/performance/#configure-the-sample-rate

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue by following expo-documentation.
As they do not mention performance monitoring, one parameter is missing in the init:

```js
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/react-native";

Sentry.init({
  dsn: YOUR_DNS,
  // Set tracesSampleRate to 1.0 to capture 100% of transactions for performance monitoring.
  // We recommend adjusting this value in production.
  tracesSampleRate: 1.0, <--- This one
});
```

You can find this snippet in the sentry starter kit tutorial for react-native.